jupyter notebook отладка
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, актуальной инструкцией как настроить отладку в jupyter notebook для python. Поиском пользовался, найденного мало и оно очень поверхностное.Например xeus-python это самое актуальное решение для jupyter?
Спасибо.

хороши модули для vs code

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html
